# C++ strings: [] vs. *

Tags: c++, syntax, reference, pointers

Been thinking, what's the difference between declaring a variable with [] or * ? The way I see it:

```
char *str = new char[100];
char str2[] = "Hi world!";
```

.. should be the main difference, though Im unsure if you can do something like

```
char *str = "Hi all";
```

.. since the pointer should the reference to a static member, which I don't know if it can?

Anyways, what's really bugging me is knowing the difference between:

```
void upperCaseString(char *_str) {};
void upperCaseString(char _str[]) {};
```

So, would be much appreciated if anyone could tell me the difference? I have a hunch that both might be compiled down the same, except in some special cases?

Ty

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Let's look into it (for the following, note `char const` and `const char` are the same in C++):

### String literals and char *

`"hello"` is an array of 6 const characters: `char const[6]`. As every array, it can convert implicitly to a pointer to its first element: `char const * s = "hello";` For compatibility with C code, C++ allows one other conversion, which would be otherwise ill-formed: `char * s = "hello";` it removes the const!. This is an exception, to allow that C-ish code to compile, but it is deprecated to make a `char *` point to a string literal. So what do we have for `char * s = "foo";` ?

`"foo"` -> `array-to-pointer` -> `char const*` -> `qualification-conversion` -> `char *`. A string literal is read-only, and won't be allocated on the stack. You can freely make a pointer point to them, and return that one from a function, *without* crashing :).

#### Initialization of an array using a String literal

Now, what is `char s[] = "hello";` ? It's a *whole* other thing. That will create an array of characters, and fill it with the String `"hello"`. The literal isn't pointed to. Instead it is copied to the character-array. And the array is created *on the stack*. You cannot validly return a pointer to it from a function.

### Array Parameter types.

How can you make your function accept an array as parameter? You just declare your parameter to be an array:

```
void accept_array(char foo[]);
```

but you omit the size. Actually, any size would do it, as it is just ignored: The Standard says that parameters declared in that way will be transformed to be the same as

```
void accept_array(char * foo);
```

#### Excursion: Multi Dimensional Arrays

Substitute `char` by any type, including arrays itself:

```
void accept_array(char foo[][10]);
```

accepts a two-dimensional array, whose last dimension has size 10. *The first element of a multi-dimensional array is its first sub-array of the next dimension*! Now, let's transform it. It will be a pointer to its first element again. So, actually it will accept a pointer to an array of 10 chars: (remove the `[]` in head, and then just make a pointer to the type you see in your head then):

```
void accept_array(char (*foo)[10]);
```

As arrays implicitly convert to a pointer to their first element, you can just pass an two-dimensional array in it (whose last dimension size is 10), and it will work. Indeed, that's the case for *any* n-dimensional array, including the special-case of `n = 1`;

### Conclusion

```
void upperCaseString(char *_str) {};
```

and

```
void upperCaseString(char _str[]) {};
```

are the same, as the first is just a pointer to char. But note if you want to pass a String-literal to that (say it doesn't change its argument), then you should change the parameter to `char const* _str` so you don't do deprecated things.

Comment: You know, I'd never taken the time myself to understand the complexities of [] array vs pointer declaration. I'd always just used explicit length arrays or pointers. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

The three different declarations let the pointer point to different memory segments:

```
char* str = new char[100];
```

lets str point to the heap.

```
char str2[] = "Hi world!";
```

puts the string on the stack.

```
char* str3 = "Hi world!";
```

points to the data segment.

The two declarations

```
void upperCaseString(char *_str) {};
void upperCaseString(char _str[]) {};
```

are equal, the compiler complains about the function already having a body when you try to declare them in the same scope.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I had left two negative comments. That's not really useful; I've removed them.

- The following code initializes a char pointer, pointing to the start of a dynamically allocated memory portion (in the heap.)

```
char *str = new char[100];
```

This block can be freed using `delete []`.

- The following code creates a char array in the stack, initialized to the value specified by a string literal.

```
char [] str2 = "Hi world!";
```

This array can be modified without problems, which is nice. So

```
str2[0] = 'N';
cout << str2;
```

should print `Ni world!` to the standard output, making certain knights feel very uncomfortable.

- The following code creates a char pointer in the stack, pointing to a **string literal**... The pointer can be reassigned without problems, but the pointed block cannot be modified (this is undefined behavior; it segfaults under Linux, for example.)

```
char *str = "Hi all";
str[0] = 'N'; // ERROR!
```

- The following two declarations

```
void upperCaseString(char *_str) {};
void upperCaseString(char [] _str) {};
```

look the same **to me**, and in your case (you want to uppercase a string in place) it really doesn't matters.

However, all this begs the question: why are you using `char *` to express strings in C++?

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement to the answers already given, you should read through [the C FAQ regarding arrays vs. pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/). Yes it's a C FAQ and not a C++ FAQ, but there's little substantial difference between the two languages in this area.

Also, as a side note, avoid naming your variables with a leading underscore. That's reserved for symbols defined by the compiler and standard library.

Comment: That's not true. Symbols with an initial underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation. Underscore followed by lowercase is fine, in C++ at least. I haven't checked the C standard, but it reserves all kinds of stuff, including function names starting with s or w IIRC.

Comment: Okay, to clear this up the rule seems to be that leading underscores followed by a capital letter are always reserved, and leading underscores followed by a lowercase letter are reserved only in std:: and in the global namespace, so a leading underscore on a member is actually OK.

Comment: "reserved only in std:: and ::". I don't quite understand that, since you can't add symbols to std:: anyway (that is, the entire namespace is reserved for the implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Please also take a look at the http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html The C-FAQ might prove to be an interesting read in itself.

Answer (score -1):

The first option dynamically allocates 100 bytes.

The second option statically allocates 10 bytes (9 for the string + nul character).

Your third example shouldn't work - you're trying to statically-fill a dynamic item.

As to the `upperCaseString()` question, once the C-string has been allocated and defined, you can iterate through it either by array indexing or by pointer notation, because an array is really just a convenient way to wrap pointer arithmetic in C.

---

(That's the simple answer - I expect someone else will have the authoritative, complicated answer out of the spec :))

Comment: The third example does work, it will point to read-only memory containing the string. However, if you try to change it, you're in trouble.

Comment: Guess it depends on your compiler... or the error-level you have set: last time I did #3 it cranked-out a slew of warning and a coupe errors.

Comment: #3 warns in GCC with -Wwrite-strings, but that's not included in either -Wall or -Wextra. literal -> non-const char* is deprecated, I think, so a warning is reasonable.

Comment: I do tend to have my error/warning levels quite high, so this may be behavior I see that isn't default :)