# What does the compiler do to perform a cast operation in C++?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do C/C++ compilers handle type casting between types with different value ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340413/how-do-c-c-compilers-handle-type-casting)

What does the compiler do to perform a cast operation in C++?

Explain with some sample C++ code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/340413/how-do-c-c-compilers-handle-type-casting .

Comment: could u give brief detail about exactly you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard sections

> 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.2.10 and 5.2.11

give a good idea on how these casts work (which is what compiler and/or runtime implement).

reinterpret_cast is the only one whose behavior is kind of implementation defined.