# What is the meaning of this expression (char *) in C?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

Very new to C here and I think I just barely grasp the concept of pointers, but the syntax is a bit confusing so I'm having trouble trying to understand what this expression `x = (char *) &a;` means.

Rest of function for reference:

```
#include<stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   int a; 
   char *x; 
   x = (char *) &a; 
   a = 512; 
   x[0] = 1; 
   x[1] = 2; 
   printf("%d\n",a);   
   return 0; 
}
```

More specifically, why is it necessary to write `x = (char *) &a;` instead of just `x = &a;`? What does the added `(char *)` do to alter the expression?

Comment: Might I ask, where did you get this code from?

Comment: @octopus There is no implicit conversion from the type int * that is the type of the expression &a to the type char * that is the type of x.

Comment: it allows to access the individual bytes of the `int`. Endian-dependent it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do C/C++ compilers handle type casting between types with different value ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/340413/608639) and [What does a C cast really do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13746136/608639)

Comment: Accessing the `int`, after it was modified using `char*` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @EugeneSh. What makes it UB?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Are you sure it is? Because I think `a` has a declared type `int`. From what I understand, it should be okay.

Comment: @SombreroChicken dbush have updated their answer about it. Technically, after you have written it using `char*`, the object is becoming of type `char` array, and reading it as `int` would be a strict-aliasing rule violation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. That would have been true for malloc'd objects. But since `a` here has a declared type, it won't change type to char array and reading it as an integer won't violate strict aliasing. Unless ofcourse int has a trap representation and it is set to that.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya You are right.It has a declared type, and it's *stored* value can be accessed by an lvalue of a character type. Yet I can't find a reference regarding the *storing* of the value.

Comment: @EugeneSh. regarding the storing, I think you can always write to an object using an lvalue of `char` type. And you can always read (or write) it with an lvalue of its declared type (if it exists).

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Looks like a moot point like the whole strict-aliasing thing.. It can definitely lead to UB if resulting in trap. But I don't know if it is enough to say it is UB in general...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558837/what-exactly-is-a-type-cast-in-c-c). It tells the compiler that it should interpret `&a` as a `char*` instead of a `int*` which is it's actual type.

Not making this cast would get you a compilation error as the types don't match, you're basically telling the compiler "I know what I'm doing and I'm sure this is a `char*`" thus allowing you to approach type `X` as if it was type `Y`.

Normally, casting a pointer of type `X` to `Y` and trying to dereference it through type `Y` would violate the [strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule) but in this case because we're aliasing through `char*` it is allowed.

In this context it allows you to access the individual bytes of the `int` (by `x[]`), do note that the result will be different depending on the endianness of the machine (big or little).

Comment: aaah with such a good answer, I was wondering. You got c++ gold that's cheatin' :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I'm extremely sorry, it won't happen again.

Comment: You could be more clear about what a cast is: A conversion of a value from its original type to the one in the parentheses. There is nothing magic about it; it has exactly the same semantics as an implicit  conversion in an assignment, say of an int to a float (where one would be allowed); it's just that some conversions must be made explicit for safety, as -- at least for the past 30 years or so -- in the OP's case. Such a conversion may (like in int -> float) or may not (like here, probably) alter the physical representation of the value.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I'll be watching you.

Comment: thanks for the explanation @SombreroChicken! Just a quick question though - is this typecasting only needed with char?

Comment: @doctopus No, for any type `X` you want the compiler to treat as `Y`.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **type cast**.  It allows explicit conversion from one type to another.

If you just did this:

```
x = &a;
```

You would be trying to assign a `int *` to a `char *`.  Converting between the two types is not normally allowed, and the compiler will typically give a warning if you do so.

The cast explicitly tells the compiler to treat an expression as a different type.  In this case:

```
 x = (char *) &a;
```

The cast says to explicitly convert `&a`, which has type `int *`, to an expression of type `char *`.  This expression can then be assigned to `x` with no warnings.

In most cases, converting from one pointer type to another invokes implementation or undefined defined behavior, however converting to a `char *` is allowed, as it allows you to access the individual bytes of a datatype consisting of multiple bytes.  What you can't do however is use a `char *` which points to an object of a different type to *write* to that object.  Doing so risks creating a trap representation, and subsequently attempting to read the original datatype would invoke [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).