# Populate a vector<int> from integers in a char *

Tags: c++, stl, vector

```
char *values = "   3   1   4 15";

vector<int> array;
```

I want to populate the array with the values,

3,1,4,15

Is there a slick way to do it with the stl copy algorithm?

Comment: beware that using char* instead of char const* is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308279/c-vs#308724

Comment: note that vector<int> array((istream_iterator<int>(iss)), istream_iterator<int>()); works too

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Indeed there is:

```
std::istringstream iss(values);
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(iss), 
          std::istream_iterator<int>(), 
          std::back_inserter(array));
```

Comment: Yep, right on target.
I feel more educated already.
Thank you.