# Is there any benefit to declaring local variables const?

Tags: c++, variables, constants

If I have a function which only exists for a short amount of time, does making the list of colors a constant make a difference?

```
string getrandcolor(){
    const string colors[5] = {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "purple"};
    return colors[rand() % 5];
}
```

Note: The actual list of colors contains hundreds of colors not just the small sample I have shown, not sure if this makes a difference either.

Comment: Do you call this function often?

Comment: @Tommy: The string is copied on return, since it's return-by-value.

Comment: @Cameron: Whoops, for some reason I thought he was returning a pointer.

Comment: @cameron It's difficult to say, it could be called a lot of times, it could be called none, it depends on what the user is doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does const-correctness give the compiler more room for optimization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313730/does-const-correctness-give-the-compiler-more-room-for-optimization)

Comment: It makes a difference in that it communicates clearly to future programmers that that variable is supposed to be a constant. It also provides a nice compilation error if someone tries to modify the variable in the future.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It prevents you from accidentally overwriting variables that you didn't mean to change. "Oops!"-protection is probably `const`'s most important function.

Hypothetically a compiler could divine some kind of optimization from knowing a variable isn't supposed to change, but my testing has never found one that actually does something meaningful in the situation you describe.

const [**static**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd.aspx) *does* have an important difference in your particular code sample. Because your colors[] array is local, it must be constructed afresh each time the `getrandcolor()` function is called. That means the string constructor gets run five times each time you call `getrandcolor()`, which is very wasteful. const **static** means that the data is constructed only once — the first time the function is run — and put into a shared memory space.

Comment: `static` is likely to have more of an impact than `const` here so +1 for mentioning it.

Comment: "It must be constructed afresh" I'm not sure that this is true. It probably _will_ be, but I don't think that "it must be" is accurate.

Comment: That is really interesting thanks, however what would happen if I had function A with variable X and function B with another variable called X and they were both of the same type but were supposed to be different, would they inherit the data of each other?

Comment: @Mark No, static local variables inside a function are only visible inside that function. They are "locally scoped." You can learn more about static local variables here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1sb61xd(v=VS.100).aspx     and the implications of returning them from functions here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/959951/returning-reference-to-static-local-variable-in-c

Answer (score 7):

In terms of performance? No, probably not. It looks like your array could be `static` too, and then perhaps *yes*.

In terms of code style? Possibly. Though the addition of `const` makes your code a little verbose, it also makes clear that the data is not to be modified. This is both *documenting* and *safe*.

---

Ideally, all objects in C++ would be constants by default, and you'd have to write `mutable` to make them variables. It's all backwards!

Comment: "Ideally, all **variables** in C++ would be **const** by default" - let's think about that for a bit :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Objects. "Ideally, all variables in C++ would _instead_ be const by default."  Shut up. :)

Comment: Ideally, "variables" would be referred to as "named objects" ;-)

Comment: "Ideally all names would refer to const objects by default, and require using some keyword to indicate the mutable references"

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about performance, then: **no**, it shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 2):

By declaring a local variable a const, you gain the following benefits:

- Correctness: the compiler will ensure that you won't accidentally change the value of the variable.
- Clarity: you clearly document that the variable is a constant.

(By the way, I am not sure what is constant in that specific example. More soon...)

Comment: The strings are constant. `colors` is an `lvalue array of 5 constant strings`.

Comment: I just went checking for that :)

Comment: Nothing, as you can't assign to an array. That's what happens when one stops using a language daily -- I keep forgetting the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Talking about performances, but also code readability, you should create the "colors" variable outside the function ( since a hundred-sized array is quite a huge amount of code, masking the logic of the function) either in an initialization  function, or at global level. 
If you don't consider extract this variable, at least, make it static.

If this array is used only during a short period during the program execution, you may consider fill it before the first call to getcolors and eventually free it when you're sure you will not require it anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different example:

```
const int *global_ptr = 0;

void bar();

void foo() {
    int x = 1;
    global_ptr = &x;
    bar();
    std::cout << x << "\n";
}
```

The compiler cannot optimize the last line to use the value `1`, because for all it knows, `bar()` takes the value of `global_ptr`, converts it to `int*`, and modifies `x` through it. This would be somewhat risky coding, but casting away a const qualifier and mutating is valid provided that the referand is really mutable, so the compiler must allow for it.

But, if `x` were marked `const` then it would be *invalid* for `bar()` to cast away const and mutate, and so the optimizer is free to assume that `x` still holds the value `1` when it is printed.

Optimizers certainly do identify compile-time constants for this kind of optimization, so I wouldn't be surprised to see it make a difference to emitted code. How much difference it makes to performance, I don't know. It's not hard to generate cases where identifying a constant can for example replace an (expensive) division with some (cheaper) bit twiddling, or can allow expressions involving `x` and a bunch of other constants to be calculated at compile time instead of runtime.

Also, link-time optimization might allow `bar` to be inlined, in which case the link-time optimizer can inspect its contents more closely, and might be able to rule out its modifying `x` even in the non-const case.

In your example, though, no reference to `colors` can escape to unknown code, so the difference doesn't arise. Anyway, a const string is probably harder to optimize with than a const int, so there's even less chance you're enabling some brilliant optimization by using `const`.