# c string allocation differences?

Tags: c

I have a functions which takes a char * as its only argument.  I then perform some strtok operations on it.  Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesent.  It working depends upon how the string was constructed.  For instance here are the two cases.

```
int main()
{
   char glob[] = "/abc/def/ghi";
   char *glob2 = "/abc/def/ghi";

   func(glob);  //this one works
   func(glob2); //this one doesnt work

   return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between the two allocation methods and why does strtok blow up on the second one?

Comment: Read litb's excellent post for the difference between char[] and char* - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308279/c-strings-vs/308724#308724

Comment: Assigning a string constant to a char* (instead of a const char*) is only legal for historical reasons. It is considered deprecated, and some compilers will issue you a warning about it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`strtok()` basically modifies the input string.

```
char *glob2 = "/abc/def/ghi";
```

In above case the `glob2` points to read-only data and hence it fails, whereas with '`char glob[] = "/abc/def/ghi";`' the data is not read-only, it's available in char array. Hence it allows the modifications.

Comment: Quoting from the man page:

Be cautious when using these functions.  If you do use them, note that:

       - These functions modify their first argument.

       - These functions cannot be used on constant strings.

       - The identity of the delimiting character is lost.

       - The strtok() function uses a static buffer while parsing, so it’s not thread safe.  Use strtok_r() if this matters to you.

Answer (score 7):

char[] str1 = "foo"  allocates an array of the chars on the stack (assuming this is inside a function). That array can be modified without a problem.

const char *str = "foo"  gives you a pointer to the string foo, which will usually reside in read-only memory.

char *str = "foo"  will do the same thing but implicitly remove the const (without actually changing the fact that the pointer likely points to read-only memory).

Answer (score 6):

Strtok writes to the memory allocated to the string.

You cannot write to statically allocated string memory on most compilers/runtimes/hardware. You can write to the stack.

Answer (score -1):

The other comments are correct; you should use strtok_r() instead.

Comment: -1, since strtok_r doesn't actually relate directly to the problem here: *Both* strtok_r and strtok modify the input buffer